# Web page Embedded in a webpage, interacting with Watir elements

Tags: frame, watir

I am having problems accessing a text field on a web site. What code would I write to input data into the input field `txtUser`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly say the text field is in a frame:

```
browser.frame(:name => "content").text_field(:name => "txtUser").set "Lorem Ipsum"
```